# XMMATRIX performance

Tags: mathematics, directx, directxmath

Dears,
I am facing a performance problem when I try to access cell 42 and 43 in XMMATRIX define in DirectXMath.h. The frames dropped by 100 FPS.

Here is my code:

```
for (int index = 0; index < m_CopyOfCascadeConfig.m_nCascadeLevels; ++index)
    {
        XMMATRIX mShadowTexture = m_matShadowProj[index] * dxmatTextureScale * dxmatTextureTranslation;

        XMStoreFloat4x4(&mShadowTextureFlt, mShadowTexture);

        // This is the line that cause the performance drop
        pcbAllShadowConstants->m_vCascadeOffset[index] =
            XMVectorSet(mShadowTextureFlt._41, mShadowTextureFlt._42, mShadowTextureFlt._43, 0.0);
}
```

I also tried to use the folowing but no hope:

```
pcbAllShadowConstants->m_vCascadeOffset[index] = mShadowTexture.r[3];
```

Any suggestes will be appreciated.

Comment: "Dropped by 100 FPS" is not... not a statement of how much time something took. If you dropped from 1 million FPS to 999900 FPS then... it's irrelevant, move on to other things! If you dropped from 101 to 1 then it's an actual issue. Are you sure this is an issue?

Comment: What happens if you do `pcbAllShadowConstants->m_vCascadeOffset[index] = XMVectorSet(0,0,0,0);` - the slow down you describe is more likely to come from updating the constant buffer.

Comment: It is dropped from 650 FPS to 550 FPS

Comment: Yes, When I tried XMVectorSet(0,0,0,0) FPS goes to 650 FPS, when I tried by above code it is dropped to 550 FPS again.